# List of applications that are visible

Tags: windows, desktop

Is there a way in windows to get a list of all applications that are visible on the screen? Can I get a list of all windows of each application, their sizes and position?

Comment: maybe this should be three questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows you can use the function EnumDesktopWindows() to enumerate over all the top level windows on a desktop. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682615(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: [EnumWindows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497.aspx) enumerates all top-level windows on the current desktop. I take the *"visible on the screen"* part of the question to mean *"on the current desktop"*.

Comment: Gets windows on specific desktop or current desktop if first parm is null.  There is also [EnumDesktops](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682615(v=vs.85).aspx) for enumerating all desktops